# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, javafx

When I changed jdk in my project from 8 to 11 I have cought this problem:

Full stack of error:

```
2019-08-12 14:54:47.216 FINE    [Stock] : configuring... 
2019-08-12 14:54:47.243 FINE    [Stock] CryptoStock: configuring... 
2019-08-12 14:54:47.243 FINE    [Stock] CryptoStock: configuring... 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.exscudo.desktop.cryptoterminal.utils.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/terminal/usr_desktop-client/build/) to field java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.lookup
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.exscudo.desktop.cryptoterminal.utils.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-08-12 14:54:49.623 INFO    [Stock] >Exception in Application start method 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.633 INFO    [Stock] >Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.639 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.641 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.645 INFO    [Stock] >    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.647 INFO    [Stock] >Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.653 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:901) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.656 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:945) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.657 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:194) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.658 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:718) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.659 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2681) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.660 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2501) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.661 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2415) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.662 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3188) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.664 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3149) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.666 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3122) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.667 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.667 INFO    [Stock] >    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3090) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.668 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.exscudo.desktop.cryptoterminal.App.start(App.java:412) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.669 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.670 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.671 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.672 INFO    [Stock] >    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.673 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.674 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.675 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.676 INFO    [Stock] >    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174) 
2019-08-12 14:54:49.679 INFO    [Stock] >    ... 1 more 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Error is here:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Terminal.fxml"), rb);
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>desktop-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>Terminal</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>version.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>font/*.ttf</include>
                    <include>fxml/**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.png</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>images/**/*.svg</include>
                    <include>sound/*.wav</include>
                    <include>style/**/*.css</include>
                    <include>bundle/*.properties</include>
                    <include>testdata/*.*</include>
                    <include>com/**/*</include>
                    <include>welcome/**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>version.txt</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <mainClass>com.desktop.terminal.App</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>lib/ribbon-1.0.jar lib/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ribbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/static/lib/ribbon-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.14</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/static/lib/controlsfx-8.40.14.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric.centerdevice</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafxsvg</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JFREECHART -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart-fx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- external API dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- client maven -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.novsys</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib_uni-analysis</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcprov-ext-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcpkix-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle.bcmail-jdk15on.1.57.org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.57</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sourceforge-igetdb</id>
            <name>igetdb repository as joone source</name>
            <url>http://igetdb.sourceforge.net/maven2-repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: ok, so your problem is: you call a method that doesn't exist. What's not to get? but, even though this is a stacktrace, it's logged as INFO messages (no idea why though), so it shouldn't pose a problem (or at least not that much of one)

Comment: maybe the function you called is in Java 11 `private`.

Comment: @Raw that would lead to an "is not visible" error message. Maybe he's using versions that aren't compatible.

Comment: Are you adding the JavaFX jars to the module path, are you adding `javafx.fxml` to `--add-modules`? Please provide more details on how you run your project (VM arguments or build files (pom.xml/build.gradle)

Comment: Sorry, I added pom.xml

Comment: Could be related to this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218720

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am not using GMapsFX 2.12.0

Comment: Thanks everyone for ansvers, I solved this problem. This problem was because I mixed difference version of java. FXMLLoader used from jdk 8.

Comment: @PeterPetrov what did you replace FXMLLoader with in Java 11?